# Re-raise in original context for debugging purposes

Tags: python, debugging, exception, pdb

I'm looking to do something like this, but I want to raise the exception in a way that when I am using pdb, it will drop me in the risky_func

```
def outer_func(debug=True):
    for i in some_lst:
        try:
            risky_func(i)
        except Exception as e:
            if debug:
                 raise e  # go back to risky_func context in stack where exception originally occurred
                 # alternatively: pdb.set_trace(), but also going back to risky_func context
            else:
                 pass
```

The only thing I can think of is putting the try/catch in risky_func and passing the debug parameter to it, but this would be really inelegant

Comment: if you want console debugging, I think you should try `pudb`

Comment: How about using `finally` block?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `raise e`, Python cannot know whether `e` is something new or still the same exception as before. If you just use `raise` on its own, it will throw the same exception again as last time.

The same concept exists in other languages, e.g. C#. Compare `throw e;` and `throw;` (without `e`).

Both, Python and C#, will assign a new stack trace to the exception if you use `e`. It will use the original stacktrace without `e`.